# Sort a pivot table according to % of Row Total

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My pivot table compute the `sum` of sales amount of products in different regions (row field) according to product type (column field). The values which we want is the `% of Row Total` (so that we can look at, for each region, the % of sales amounts of each product type out of the total amounts of the region). An example:

```
           Type A    Type B    Type C
Region 1      32%       41%       27%
Region 2      25%       50%       25%
Region 3      26%       40%       34%
```

Row and Column totals are not shown in the table above.

Question: How to sort the Regions according to the percentage of the product type that we select? (Except by manually doing the drag-and-drop.)
For example, we want to sort the percentages of Type B in descending order like this:

```
           Type A    Type B    Type C
Region 2      25%       50%       25%
Region 1      32%       41%       27%
Region 3      26%       40%       34%
```

The difficulty is that, the sorting by right-clicking the column for Type B does not sort the regions in the way that we want. MS Excel sorts the regions **according to the summed sales amount** rather than the %. In my case, Region 3 has the greatest sales amount for Type B. Imagine, or try, the following data:

```
Type    Region    Amount   Quarter
Type A  Region 1    $150   Q1 
Type A  Region 2    $120   Q1
Type A  Region 3    $240   Q1 
Type B  Region 1    $200   Q1
Type B  Region 2    $250   Q1
Type B  Region 3    $450   Q1
Type C  Region 1    $160   Q1
Type C  Region 2    $100   Q1
Type C  Region 3    $380   Q1
Type A  Region 1    $170   Q2 
Type A  Region 2    $130   Q2
Type A  Region 3    $280   Q2 
Type B  Region 1    $210   Q2
Type B  Region 2    $250   Q2
Type B  Region 3    $350   Q2
Type C  Region 1    $110   Q2
Type C  Region 2    $150   Q2
Type C  Region 3    $300   Q2
```

Note: we use MS Excel 2010.)